# Function Overloading using Enum

Tags: c++, enums, overloading

I was going through examples of function overloading and came across the following example:

```
#include <string>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

enum e1 {a1, b1, c1};
enum e2 {a2, b2, c2 = 0x80000000000 };

string format (int){
    cout<<1;
}
string format (unsigned int){
    cout<<2;
}


int main () { 
    format (a1);
    format (a2);
    return 0; 
}
```

Using gcc 5.4.0, `format(a1)` compiles and `format(int)` is called (displays 1 as output). But, when `format(a2)` is compiled, the following error appears:

```
 call of overloaded 'format(e2)' is ambiguous
```

Shouldn't `format(a2)` and `format(a1)` have the same output/error?

Comment: After fixing the compile error (`std::`) and then the crasher bug (no returns) it works fine for me `GCC 7.2`

Comment: What compiler are you using? AFAIK the underlying datatype is implementation dependent (may be int, unsigned int, unsigned long, ecc.)... I think that by not assigning a value the enum-type is handled as int and in the case of a2 (assigning 0x80000000 which should be greater INT_MAX) it is probably interpreted as long (where the compiler does not know to what it should be casted to)

Comment: Using http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/underlying_type I have found that on my system both enums use unsigned as underlying type

Comment: Tested it with MSVC (VS2015) and it works in both cases, cause both enums are strictly interpreted as integer (e2::c2 == -2147483648)

Comment: @Justin Updated the code. The value of c2 was meant to be 0x80000000000. The compiler I am using is gcc 5.4.0

Comment: Reproduced on clang: https://godbolt.org/g/B5mUaE

Comment: There is no return statement for your format functions. Are they supposed to return strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> enum e2 {a2, b2, c2 = 0x80000000000 };
> ```

The literal `0x80000000000` is of type `long`. A regular `enum` (not an `enum class`) has an underlying type large enough to hold all its values <sup>[7.2 [dcl.enum]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.enum#7)</sup>, thus `e2` must be at least a `long`.

On the other hand, `e1`'s values all fit inside an `int`/`unsigned int`, so its underlying type must be one of those.

When [I tested it on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/d3hDKh), the underlying type of `e1` was `unsigned int`, and the underlying type of `e2` was `unsigned long`. Thus, when calling the functions, `format(a1)` unambiguously calls the `unsigned int` version, but `format(a2)` now has to convert from an `unsigned long`, so it's unclear which function to call.